# Getting id of tr element if the checkboxes is checked

Tags: jquery

With below code I get of `tr` elements `id` attributes:

```
var IDs = [];
$(".head").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
alert(IDs);
```

These `tr` elements have checkboxes.

What I want is that if checkboxes are checked then I have these `tr` ids. I need checked checkboxes `tr` ids :)

How can I achieve it?

Comment: brother work on your accept ratio man! cheers :)

Comment: Do you mean that your `.head` elements are checkboxes, and you want to get the `id` of their parent `tr`?

Comment: .head is tr's class and tr checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this to get the parent id of the ticked checkboxes...

```
    var IDs = [];
    $(".head input:checked").each(function(){ IDs.push($(this).parent().attr("id")); });
    alert(IDs);
```

Here's a working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/uMfe3/

Comment: dude,        $('#'+Ids).each('slow', function() {
    }).slideUp(); this does not work what might be the problem?

Comment: That's a completely different question - create a new question and post full code to outline the problem, preferably with a link to something like jsfiddle to show us.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like so...

```
var Ids = $('.head:has(:checkbox:checked)')
           .map(function() { return this.id })
           .get();
```

If you wanted it to execute faster by having jQuery leverage `querySelectorAll()` internally, you could use...

```
var Ids = $('.head').filter(function() {
              return $(this).has('input[type="checkbox"]') && this.checked;
          });
```

...to get a jQuery collection of `.head` elements which contain a checked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var IDs = [];
//iterate over your <tr>
$(".head").each(function(){ 
    //if there is atleas a checked checkbox
    if($('input:checkbox:checked', this).length > 0){ 
        //add the id of the <tr>
        IDs.push(this.id); 
    }
});

alert(IDs);
```

or you could do

```
$(".head input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){ 
    IDs.push(this.id); 
});
```

Comment: @MertMetin there was a typo i think (lenght instead of length)

Comment: $('#'+Ids).each('slow', function() { }).slideUp(); this does not work what might be the problem? –